# how do i solve a transforming timestamp gives me an error?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

```
trades = pd.DataFrame(binance_client.get_my_trades(symbol='ADAUSDT'))
trades['time'] = pd.to_datetime(trades["time"],unit="ms", origin=pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01'))
trades.to_csv()
```

The error is that it returns 22/01/2052 01:26:52 a.m. but the correct year is 2022. The rest of the date is correct.

I don´t know if it is the format, but the output looks strange.

Comment: Would require more information, what was originally contained in Time column. Provide it

Comment: Try to correct the year by subtracting 50 years to see if that solves the problem:`trades['time'] = trades['time'] - pd.Timedelta(years=50)`

Answer (score 0):

The origin for dates is usually 1970-01-01, not 2000-01-01.
Try keeping the default origin in pd.to_datetime:

```
trades['time'] = pd.to_datetime(trades["time"], unit="ms", origin='unix')
```